# how to extract string and store to database using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

ID | RECORDTYPE | RECORDNUMBER | SOURCESYSTEMID | TARGETSYSTEMID |

I have problem to extract this data and store it in array list and insert into database. Could you please help me?..

This is my code:-

```
public void massageData(String tmp) {
    String Id = "";
    String RecordType = "";
    String RecordNumber = "";
    String sourceSystemId = "";
    String targetSystemId = "";
    String TelNo = "";

    String[] recArray = tmp.split("\\|");

    RecordType = recArray[1].trim();
    RecordNumber = recArray[2].trim();
    sourceSystemId = recArray[3].trim();
    targetSystemId = recArray[4].trim();
    TelNo = recArray[5].trim();

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    String actualMSISDN = parseMSISDN(TelNo);

    String iCtr = getiCtr(actualMSISDN);
    Id = recArray[0].trim();
    String stateCode = lookupStateCode(State);
    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        // insert post process data to data_999 table
        String sQuery = "insert into DATA_999 (ID,RecordType,RecordNumber,SourceSystemApplicationId,TargetApplicationId,TelNo) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sQuery);
        int dbStat = stmt.executeUpdate();
        int isExist = chkMsisdn(actualMSISDN);
        if(isExist > 0) {
            // retrieve record from database
            icData oldData = getRecord(actualMSISDN);

            icData newData = new icData();
            stmt.setString(1, Id);
            stmt.setString(2, RecordType);
            stmt.setString(3, RecordNumber);
            stmt.setString(4, sourceSystemId);
            stmt.setString(5, targetSystemId);
            stmt.setString(6, TelNo);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch(SQLException s) {
        logger.error(s.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
        }
        try {
            if(conn != null) conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

anyone find any mistakes inside this code?..please help me!!..I spend two week to find out what is the problem..arrgghhh..>_<..
your attention, help and support are much appreciated!..thank you..:)

Comment: I think,recArray  will be start 0 not in 1. Pls change that and try again. If you tell me the exception it'll be very useful to help.

Comment: I already start with array[0] but still not working..any else that I missing?..really hope to get help on this matter...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be executing the statement (`stmt.executeUpdate()`) before setting the parameters (`stmt.setString()`).

Comment: owh..thank for your help!..I am really appreciate it!...yahuuu..but I still have another problem..:(..even I setString before executeUpdate, the code still not working..:(

Comment: I already start with array[0] but still not working..any else that I missing?..really hope to get help on this matter...:(

Comment: In that case you should probably start a new question. Also, you will get quicker responses if you pull out a shorter bit of code that demonstrates the problem you are now having, and describe what you want that code to do and what it actually does.

Comment: Dear Russell, thanks for the info. I will start the new question..Thank you..:)